# jQuery - Function not triggering .show(), .toggle(), or (display, block)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, show

So I have a div duplication function for when a user wants to add a speaker, and a function for deleting one of said speakers.

In the latter function, in the event that all the speakers have been removed, I want to reveal the only remaining div of class speaker (the ID doesn't matter).

My function for switching between speakers (bottom) works fine (.hide()), but not the removal function. Heck even when I take out the if statement it doesn't work. Please assist!

```
$('#submitSpeaker').click(
        function duplicateSpeaker() {
            var original = $('#speaker' + speakerCount);
            var clone = original.clone(true, true);
            var textnode = original.find('.speakerName').val();
            var node = document.createElement("LI");
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            if (textnode == '') {
                $.Dialog({
                    title: 'Wizard',
                    flat: true,
                    content: 'You must enter a Speaker Name.',
                    shadow: true,
                    padding: 10
                });
                return;
            }
            node.setAttribute('class', 'active speakerLI');
            node.setAttribute('id', 'speakerLI' + speakerCount)
            clone.attr("id", "speaker" + ++speakerCount);
            original.hide();
            original.parent().append(clone);
            a.setAttribute('class', 'gotoSpeaker');
            $(node).append(a);
            $(a).append(textnode + ' ' + "<i class='icon-minus removeSpeaker'></i>");
            document.getElementById("speakerList").appendChild(node);
            clone.find('input').val('').end();
            clone.find('textarea').val('').end();
            clone.find('img').attr('src', '#');
        });


$("#speakerList").on("click", "i.removeSpeaker", function () {
    var speakerNum = $(this).closest('li').attr('id').replace(/speakerLI/, '');        
        $('#speaker' + speakerNum).remove();
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
        if ($('.speaker').length == 1) {
            $('.speaker').show();
        };
    });

$("#speakerList").on("click", "a.gotoSpeaker", function () {
    var speakerNum = $(this).closest('li').attr('id').replace(/speakerLI/, '');
    $(".speaker").hide();
    $('#speaker' + speakerNum).show();
});
```

Comment: `if ($('.speaker').length == 1) {` are you sure there's ***only one*** element, it seems you keep adding them every time you click the button ?

Comment: Errors in the console?

Comment: Positive, I've also tried nixing the if statement altogether, and using the ID of the speaker I knew would be there by counting them out. No dice.

Comment: $('.speaker:hidden').show() didn't work, thanks though.

Comment: Ok, a fiddle would be really nice. But you append `i` to an `a` but remove `li`?!? Was a bit out with `:hidden`. Thought it would not find it then... :/

Comment: Could you add the `HTML` to this http://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/pL9ccapn/?

Comment: Yeah so the 'a' catches the gotoSpeaker function and the 'i' is a minus button that catches the removeSpeaker function. Both are inside the 'li'.
When I remove a speaker, I remove it from the list and it's corresponding div container.

Comment: Ok. The removing works? I just thought that would be the problem. But the problem is `.show()` right? I cannot see where the `.speaker` is, that's why I suggest you put some `HTML` into the fiddle. ;)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pL9ccapn/8/)

I don't know how much this will help but here ya go.

Comment: Yes removing works great, just need that last div to show up again.

Comment: Well, the problem is you have `speakerCount` not defined.

Comment: Nope I actually figured it out... very amateur mistake. Since I nested the 'i' (delete) inside of the 'a' (goTo), upon clicking it's firing both functions, so the div is going from show to hide in an instant.